# I messed up with my transform manipulation tool settings

Tags: modeling, 3d-manipulator

I didn't have any problems earlier, until I noticed that when I drag some vertices, with the Transformation Manipulators, it doesn't look aligned anymore.

[image]

So, instead of dragging the vertices to a straight in front it goes the other side.

[image]

I'm new to Blender and I didn't know what I accidentally clicked to cause this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the orientation back to global and you should be fine. I rarely ever use widgets, though.

[image]